# How to use assembly language in Xcode

Tags: xcode, assembly, directive, mnemonics

I have the below program written and tried to compile/build it in XCODE (Version 10.1 (10B61)), but failed.

```
.386
.model flat
.code

start   PROC
        mov eax,213
        add eax,432

        rel
start   endp
end     start
```

This code was extracted from a study video on assembly language and I believe XCODE is capable of handling.

However, I'm presented with the following errors,

error: unexpected token at start of statement
.386
^

error: unknown directive
.model flat
^

error: unknown directive .code
.code
^

error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'start'
start PROC
^

error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
mov eax,213
^

error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
add eax,432
^

error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'rel'
rel
^

error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'start'
start endp
^

error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'end'
end start

Can someone kindly suggest any solutions, please. By the way, I'm a novice to programming as well and this is the first time I have used XCODE.

Regards
Thusitha

Comment: That's MASM syntax (the assembler that comes with Visual Studio).  XCode uses clang, which like GCC uses GAS syntax for directives, and by default AT&T syntax for instructions.  Look at the asm output of a C program you compile, like in [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116).  Or search for MacOS asm example: anything more than just returning a value is going to depend on calling conventions and x86-64 vs. i386 differences; asm is not portable.  Also, `rel` isn't an instruction; you probably meant `ret`.